# Conditionally summarizing when condition involves grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to summarize a dataframe, grouping it by two variables. The problem is that I want to sum a third variable just when one of the grouping variables matches a pattern.

As an example:

```
a<-c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C')
b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
c<-c('a1', 'a1', 'b2', 'a1', 'b2', 'a1', 'a1')

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

I would like to group rows by variables `a` and `c` and create a summarizing variable summing `b` value of those rows in which `a == 'A'.

I try:

```
df1<-df %>% group_by(a,c) %>% summarize(sumc=if(a == 'A'){sum(b)} else{unique(b)})
```

but I get:

```
Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `sumc = if (...) NULL`.
ℹ In group 1: `a = "A"`, `c = "a1"`.
Caused by error in `if (a == "A") ...`:
! the condition has length > 1
```

This is the output I expect:

```
a    b    c
A    3    a1
A    3    b2
B    4    a1
B    5    b2
C    13   a1
```

Do you know how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::count` is a nice shortcut for `group_by(GROUPING_COLS) |> summarise(b = sum(THING_TO_COUNT))`

```
df |>
  count(a, c, wt = as.numeric(b), name = "b")


  a  c  b
1 A a1  3
2 A b2  3
3 B a1  4
4 B b2  5
5 C a1 13
```

(Or, if you use `df<-data.frame(a,b,c)` it won't convert the numbers in `b` into characters and you can skip the `as.numeric()` part.)

Comment: But how can you conditionally count?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between my output and what you're expecting, aside from column order. Do you want `|> filter(a == "A")` at the end?